# Display glyphicon for hovered row in bootstrap table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to display and change the color of a bootstrap glyphicon only next to the row I hover.

This is the HTML:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span></td>
            <td class="text-center">something</td>
            <td class="text-center ">something</td>
            <td class="text-danger text-center">something</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the CSS where i override the bootstrap table borders since I want none (probably can be better)

```
.custom-table {
    border-bottom:0px !important;
}

.custom-table th, .table td {
    border: 0px !important;
}

.fixed-table-container {
    border:0px !important;
}

.table-hover tbody tr:hover td, .table-hover tbody tr:hover th {
    border:0px !important;
}

.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover span, .table-hover > tbody > tr:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
 }
```

How it currently looks:
[image]

How I want it to look (if I hover over that row):
[image]

Can it be done only with css/html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `:hover` as you did then add `.glyphicon-hand-right` and a color to it

**EDIT**

> Okay but I want the others to be hidden?

New version using only CSS, using `visibility`

```css
.custom-table {
  border-bottom: 0px !important;
}

.custom-table th,
.table td {
  border: 0px !important;
}

.fixed-table-container {
  border: 0px !important;
}

.table-hover tbody tr:hover td,
.table-hover tbody tr:hover th {
  border: 0px !important;
}

.table-hover>tbody>tr:hover span,
.table-hover>tbody>tr:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.table-hover>tbody>tr .glyphicon-hand-right {
  visibility: hidden
}

.table-hover>tbody>tr:hover .glyphicon-hand-right {
  color: blue;
  visibility: visible
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span></td>
      <td class="text-center">something</td>
      <td class="text-center ">something</td>
      <td class="text-danger text-center">something</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span></td>
      <td class="text-center">something</td>
      <td class="text-center ">something</td>
      <td class="text-danger text-center">something</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Old Version - sice the question was misunderstood 
You can use jQuery for that then.

```js
$('.table-hover>tbody>tr').hover(function() {
  $(this).siblings().find('.glyphicon-hand-right').hide()
}, function() {
  $(this).siblings().find('.glyphicon-hand-right').show()
})
```

```css
.custom-table {
  border-bottom: 0px !important;
}

.custom-table th,
.table td {
  border: 0px !important;
}

.fixed-table-container {
  border: 0px !important;
}

.table-hover tbody tr:hover td,
.table-hover tbody tr:hover th {
  border: 0px !important;
}

.table-hover>tbody>tr:hover span,
.table-hover>tbody>tr:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.table-hover>tbody>tr:hover .glyphicon-hand-right {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span></td>
      <td class="text-center">something</td>
      <td class="text-center ">something</td>
      <td class="text-danger text-center">something</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span></td>
      <td class="text-center">something</td>
      <td class="text-center ">something</td>
      <td class="text-danger text-center">something</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Okay but I want the others to be hidden?

Comment: solved it with visibility, thanks didn't know it was this simple

Comment: @m_bale I just updated  the answer. Sorry for late reply. Busy working. can you send a link of your solution, just curious

Comment: So I misunderstood your question.  I thought you wanted to have all the glyphs showing in the table. But I see you just want them to show up when hovering. I can update the answer if you like

Comment: It's okay I could have described it better, thanks :)